# Saiku report is exporting to excel with uncorrect values

Tags: excel, olap, saiku

I've got a problem with exporting saiku reports to excel.

For example in saiku I've got a table like this

```
Text1 521
Text2 75
Text3 0
....
```

And after export to excel it looks like

```
Text1 521.000000123
Text2 75.0000000123
Text3 1.23e-8
```

Where can be the problem? Maybe I should add some format rules?

And also, when I'm opening the xlsx file with libreOffice - the numbers are formatted correctly.

Comment: what do you see when you export to CSV? It could be a rounding issue on your data, a rounding issue on the export routine or a problem with Excel reading the file.

Comment: In csv - the same problem. 75.0000000123 and so on.

Comment: In my queries I've got only counts, so the problem can't be in it. I think maybe something wrong with formatString pattern in xml file?

Comment: I suggest asking that question on a Saiku forum or filing a bug report. It looks like a rounding issue on saiku's reported values.